# Can multiple drivers register to handle same device in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am going through Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love and currently reading interrupt handling in Linux. Its mentioned that driver can register to handle a hardware device using the below function where the final argument dev is unique w.r.t to device. Does that mean we can't have two device drivers serving the same hardware device ? If I want to implement a keyboard driver which works along with already existing drivers, is it not possible ? Should I have to deregister the existing driver for keyboard and register the one I have written ?

```
int request_irq(unsigned int irq, irq_handler_t handler, unsigned long flags, 
const char *name, void *dev)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, interrupt request lines are shared between drivers. In such cases, the drivers provide IRQF_SHARED in flags and provide a unique dev value when calling request_irq().

Device drivers usually share interrupts when the hardware provides a single interrupt that is used for multiple components of the hardware, each of which has its own driver. In this case, the hardware will also provide interrupt status and mask bits for each of the components.

I do not know anything about your keyboard hardware, so it's difficult to say whether you could use two device drivers with it. If all you need is read access to the device and the device state does not change by the other driver, it might work.

Sharing a UART between two drivers, for example, would definitely not work because only one of the drivers would be able to read characters from the RX FIFO.